# When I run my node js application the cookie isn't saved in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, google-api-nodejs-client

When I requested through `router.post("/signin", async (req, res)`, the cookie hasn't saved in my local Chrome browser. Please help to sort out this problem.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt= require('jsonwebtoken')

const User = require("../UserSchema/Schma");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

router.use(cookieParser());


router.post("/signin", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    if (!email || !password) {
      res.json({ error: "invalid credentials you added " });
    }
    const details = await User.findOne({ email: email });
    console.log(details);
    if (!details) {
      res.json({ error: "users error" });
    }
    else
    {
      const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password,details.password);
      console.log(isMatch);
      const token= await details.generateAuthToken();
      console.log(token);
      res.cookie("jwtoken",token,{
          expiresIn:"1h",
          httpOnly:false,
          secure:false
        }
      );
      // res.cookie("rememberme", "1", { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });
      if (!isMatch) {
        res.status(400).json({ error: "invalid credientials" });
      }
      else
      {
        res.json({ message: "user signin successfully" });
      }
    }
  }
  catch {
    console.log("something going bad");
    res.status(400).json({ error: "sorry something missing" })
  }
});
```

And my function  `generateAuthToken()` is here

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt= require("jsonwebtoken");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    require:true,
  },
  email: {
      type: String,
      require:true,
  },
  phone :{
      type:Number,
      require:true,
  },
  work:{
      type:String,
      require:true,
  },
  password:{
      type:String,
      require:true,
  }
  ,
  cpassword:{
      type:String,
      require:true,
  },
  tokens:[{
      token:{
          type:String,
          require:true,
      }
  }]
});



userSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {

    if(this.isModified('password'))
    {
        this.password=await bcrypt.hash(this.password,12);
        this.cpassword=await bcrypt.hash(this.cpassword,12);
    }
    next();
})

userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken= async function(){
    try {
        let token= jwt.sign({_id:this._id},process.env.SECRET_KEY);
        this.tokens=this.tokens.concat({token:token});
        await this.save();
        return token;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

const User = mongoose.model("USER", userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to share your User model, can't say what goes on there. Maybe the problem is here `const token= await details.generateAuthToken();`
can't say what's going on in your generateAuthToken() function.
well, you can try this below code;

```
 const token = jwt.sign({id: details._id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET(Your JWT Secret), { 
                   expiresIn: "1h" })
                 res.cookie("token", token, {
                 httpOnly: false,
                 secure: false,  
               })
              res.status(200).json({ message: "user signin successfully"})
```

this works fine for me.
also, try to use this if statement before setting token

```
if (!isMatch) {res.status(400).json({ error: "invalid credientials" })}
```

what's the point if you set token before checking password.

Comment: i have updated my question . please do visit the code again . after implementing your code . the Problem is remain same

Comment: it looks like your generateAuthToken() function ok, then make sure you are using this `app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
  });`  on your root index.js or server.js. And if you still see that problem then i would say change your browser and check. Code looks fine there shouldn't be any problem.